# ffmpeg av_read_frame return error code -5

Tags: ffmpeg

I use dll of ffmpeg read the USB camera, display the picture on the control, and save the image to the file. At first, the reading is normal. The sound and image can be saved. But after reading for a few minutes, data can not be read, av_read_frame return error code is - 5, and the camera is automatically turned off. Direct use ffmpeg.exe when I go to read the camera and save the file, it won't be a problem for hours. Anybody can you tell me how to return - 5 error code and how to deal with it?
ffmpeg version is 4.2.3
The code like this:

```
while (1)
{
  if ((ret = av_read_frame(m_pVidFmtCtx, dec_pkt)) == 0)
  {
    ret = avcodec_send_packet(m_pVidFmtCtx->streams[dec_pkt->stream_index]->codec, dec_pkt);
    while(ret >= 0)
    {
      ret = avcodec_receive_frame(m_pVidFmtCtx->streams[dec_pkt->stream_index]->codec, pframe);
      sws_scale(img_rgb_ctx, pframe->data, pframe->linesize, 0, cy, dstData, dstLinesize);
      var bitmap = new Bitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, dstLinesize[0], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, convertedFrameBufferPtr);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error code: %d", ret); // Here ret is -5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg error codes based on standard POSIX error codes used on `errno`. But FFmpeg directly returns these with `AVERROR` macro and this effectively makes it a negative number.

So error code -5 is `AVERROR(EIO)`. Obviously something seriously wrong with Input/Output.